# What is the meaning of "Ha et cetera"?

Tags: meaning, latin

In William Golding´s Paper Men, the main character keeps saying "Ha et cetera". What does he mean by this? Is it simply another way of saying "ha, ha, ha" (laughter)?

Comment: Please provide context.

Comment: I checked it out on Amazon.com, and there's no way of knowing without knowing a bit about the character. It appears to be an affected way of saying _Ha, ha, ha_, but who knows? Only someone who's read the book and has been introduced to the main character. I wouldn't venture a serious guess from the 10 or 15 hits I got searching the text.

Comment: Without having read the work, I think that Singer's answer sounds plausible. (I was going to write similar but he's said it already :-) ). It's the character's affected way of bringing attention to his low opinion of various things.  I tend to add [tm] after some items with a very roughly similar aim. The phrase "Yeah, Right!" comes close.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a way in which the main character expresses sarcasm, maybe mixed with a little distrust or disdain (to a phrase/thought that is). I think an equivalent to this would be an ironic smile, or a sneer.

It is a way in which the main character responses to phrases, or thoughts, which he finds ridiculous or nonsense.

So I think the following two phrases will have roughly the same meaning:

- "He told me he saw a flying pig yesterday... Flying pigs, can you imagine it? What a nonsense..."
- "He told me he saw a flying pig yesterday... Flying pigs, can you imagine it? Ha, et cetera..."